# Let G be a group, $N<K<G$ and $N\trianglelefteq G$. Prove that $K/N \trianglelefteq G/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group, $N<K<G$ and $N\trianglelefteq G$. Prove that $K/N \trianglelefteq G/N$

What I have tried is:

Note that $1\in G$. So $1\in K$ and $N1=N\in K/N$ which shows that $K/N$ is non-empty.

Then, let $a,b\in K$. This implies that $Na,Nb\in K/N$. So $Na(Nb)^{-1}=NaNb^{-1}\in K/N$ since $ab^{-1}\in K$. So this shows that $K/N\leq G/N$.

Lastly, let $Ng\in G/N$. Then for $Nk\in K/N$, $Ng^{-1}NkNg=N(g^{-1}kg) \in K/N$.

But the problem is I can't ensure that $K \trianglelefteq G$ and $g^{-1}kg\in K$

Comment: What you are trying to prove, ain't true. E.g., let $G$ be $S_3$, let $K$ be the non-normal subgroup generated by $(12)$, let $N$ be trivial. Then $N$ is normal in $G$, $K/N$ is basically $K$, $G/N$ is basically $G$, and $K$ isn't normal in $G$. So I suspect somewhere along the way a mistake has crept into the statement of the question.

Comment: see Rotmann . Group Theory and the correspondence theorem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson or the question should be $K \trianglelefteq G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is not true in general. What is true is:

Let $G$ be a group, $N \leq K \leq G$ and $N\trianglelefteq G$. Then $K/N \trianglelefteq G/N$ if and only if $K \unlhd G$.

A counterexample to your statement would be $N \cong V_4=\{(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\} \leq K \cong D_4=\langle(13),(1234)\rangle \leq G=S_4$.